# is SQLite db remain after application shutdown?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-lifecycle

Very (very) basic question that unclear to me:
Is SQLite db remain after application shutdown with all the data that was added to it or destroyed?

If so (and I hope so), when is the the DB schema created during the app lifecycle? I would expect it to be created on app installation, 
but according to the documentation I see this is done every time that the application started.

What am I missing? 
**When is the code below executed during the application life cycle?**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }
} //DatabaseHandler
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the DB data is stored under `/data/data/<your.app.package.name>/database/` (or something similar to that). It is a physical file that remains stored on the device until your application is uninstalled or the user goes to `Settings->App->Clear Data`

the code you posted is executed the **first time ever** your app executes `getReadableDatabase` or `getWritableDatabase`. That means, the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class checks if a valid DB file exist on that location in disk. If there's no file, it executes the `onCreate` (which creates the  DB file).

excerpt from methods `getReadableDatabase` or `getWritableDatabase` documentation:

> Create and/or open a database

Comment: Thanks. and what happen during development time if I change the DB schema? In this case I do want the database to be dropped and a new one to be created. How do I do it when working with emulator? Do I have to increase the 'DATABASE_VERSION' counter for that?

Comment: few possibilities: 1) you can increase the version, which will execute `onUpgrade` which u can use to drop the table and re-create it. Or 2) Clear the App data on the device settings. 3) Delete the database file from the disk (your app have full access to that file and you can easily call `file.delete();` on it.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite database will remain after shutdown.

Try use
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST

to prevent the re-creation of the database

Comment: db will be not created again if on another calling to db, it will use the previous one..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it remains until you remove your app from the smartphone or explicitly clear the DB.
You should [check this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html), which covers a lot of sqlite for android.

Hope it helps.